# How to make Clickable on TextView for Xamarin.Droid

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement the clickable in the textview, I've already put the `android:clickable="true"`, but only with that I did not succeed. Does anyone know of any efficient methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Click` binding as in `Button`

```
local:MvxBind="Click ClickCommand"
```

Comment: Look, I tried to do what you told me, but the effect is not working yet ...

'<TextView
      
        android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android: textSize = "40dp"
        android: clickable = "true"
        android: text = "Test"
        local: MvxBind = "Click ClickCommand" />'